# when browser accesses a web enabled with CAS service second time

Tags: session, cookies, cas

After login a web enabled with *CAS* service first time successfully, I found some values in cookie.

```
  e.g. CASTGC=TGT-41-ap1exJsVgZwLCF2qBJ0D0oz7kebUDrstfGURlSi1gqxM6IHeSY
  JSESSIONID = w7k0yh9z6qpn1580iow6um3bt
```

According to my understanding, *JSESSIONID* was created, and web server or the CAS client will recognize the JSESSIONID only, CASTGC is not necessary at the second login time. Is it correct?

When I deleted the CASTGC, and accessed the same URL, the web prompt a login form to ask user/pwd. it seems CASTGC is necessary always. Could some one explain it ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of the CAS server, the JSESSIONID may be necessary during the login process. The CASTGC cookie represents the identity of the authenticated user, it is mandatory and used every time you want to access a new application.